# How to test cordova plugin while developing?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

Can someone suggest a better way to test cordova plugin while developing it.

Right now the plugin is not pushed to github nor npm.

I am adding the plugin to my cordova android project using this command.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-test-plugin
```

But if I make any modifications to the plugin in the `plugins/` folder, those changes are not reflecting.

How can I test the plugin while making changes.

Comment: Install it once. Then open your editor directly to the installed version of the plugin (platform/android/plugins/...) and make changes there. Once you're done, copy your changes back to your original file and save.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Yeah. This worked. Thanks.